# Rect hooks props and state communication problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

**I'm trying to build my first React App based on React Hooks and having hard time figuring out what is going on with my state/props and rerendering. I'm creating some small guessing game.**

I've got a parent component GameContent, that is passing to its child (Round) some props:

- currentRound (number)
- roundData (object)
- shiftRounds (function)

Through 'shiftRounds' I'm telling my parent component: 'this player gave correct answer', than function changes round and score (both in parents state).

Although it seems easy, my function inside child component, that checks if answer is correct, **always gets data from first round.**

I tried React.useRef, tried different state configuration, but still can't find solution.

```
<GameContent />

const GameContent = ({ gameOptions, gameFinish }) => {

  const [gameData, setGameData] = useState([]);
  const [round, setRound] = useState(1);
  const [score, setScore] = useState([0, 0]);

  const [ligue, dateFrom, dateTo, rounds, player1, player2] = gameOptions;

  useEffect(() => {
    //
    // Function fetches football matches. 
    //
    (async () => {
      const matchesData = await fetchMatches(ligue, dateFrom, dateTo)
      setGameData(matchesData);
    })();
  }, [])

  const nextRound = (scoringPlayer) => {
    if (round <= rounds) {
      setScore(score => {
        score[scoringPlayer] += 1;
        return score
      });
      setRound(round => round + 1);
    } else {
      finishGame()
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="text-center">
      <h2>Round {round}</h2>
      <h3>Score</h3>
      <h2>{`${score[0]} : ${score[1]}`}</h2>
      {(gameData.length) ? <Round currentRound={round} roundData={gameData[round - 1]} shiftRounds={nextRound} players={[player1, player2]} /> : <h1>Loading...</h1>}
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
<Round />

const Round = (props) => {
  const [isCheckingAnswer, setIsCheckingAnswer] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    //
    // Set eventListeners for keydown (too capture player's answer)
    //
    document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => { handleKeyPress(e) });
    setIsCheckingAnswer(false);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', (e) => { handleKeyPress(e) });
    }
  }, [props.roundData])

  const handleKeyPress = (e) => {
    if (!isCheckingAnswer) {
      e.preventDefault();
      setIsCheckingAnswer(true);
      if (keysMap[e.key] === checkGoodAnswer(props.roundData.homeTeamScore, props.roundData.awayTeamScore)) {
        const winingPlayer = isNaN(e.key / 2) ? 0 : 1;
        props.shiftRounds(winingPlayer);
      } else {
        setIsCheckingAnswer(false);
      }
    } else {
      return
    }
  }
  return (
    <>
      <Row>
        <Col xs={4}>
          <h2>{props.roundData.homeTeam}</h2>
        </Col>
        <Col xs={4}>
          <h2>vs</h2>
        </Col>
        <Col xs={4}>
          <h2>{props.roundData.awayTeam}</h2>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Row className="justify-content-center my-5">
        <Col xs={4}>
          <h3>{props.players[0]}</h3>
        </Col>
        <Col xs={4}>
          <h3>{props.players[1]}</h3>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </>
  )
}
```

Helper functions

```
const checkGoodAnswer = (homeTeamScore, awayTeamScore) => {
  if (homeTeamScore > awayTeamScore) {
    return 'homeTeam'
  } else if (homeTeamScore < awayTeamScore) {
    return 'awayTeam'
  } else {
    return 'draw'
  }
}

const keysMap = {
  'a': 'homeTeam',
  'w': 'draw',
  'd': 'awayTeam',
  '4': 'homeTeam',
  '8': 'draw',
  '6': 'awayTeam',
}
```

Fetched data sample:

```
[
{awayTeam: "Paris Saint-Germain FC"
awayTeamScore: 2
homeTeam: "Manchester United FC"
homeTeamScore: 0},
{
awayTeam: "FC Porto"
awayTeamScore: 1
homeTeam: "AS Roma"
homeTeamScore: 2
},
...
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. The problem was with the scope of function called in addEventListener,
I called it like this:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => { handleKeyPress(e) });
```

but correct way of calling it is:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress);
```

also Sagiv pointed out, that in `useEffect` all variables, that change in time and are used inside, should be included in array, like this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
      document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => { handleKeyPress(e) });
      setIsCheckingAnswer(false);
      return () => {
        document.removeEventListener('keydown', (e) => { handleKeyPress(e) });
      }
    }, [props.roundData])
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add **ALL** relevant variables / functions that are used in your `useEffect` as dependencies.

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects):

> ... make sure the array includes all values from the component scope (such as props and state) that change over time and that are used by the effect

For example in your first effect you have no dependencies in your array:

```
useEffect(() => {
    //
    // Function fetches football matches. 
    //
    (async () => {
      const matchesData = await fetchMatches(ligue, dateFrom, dateTo)
      setGameData(matchesData);
    })();
  }, [])
```

But you do use `ligue`, `dateFrom`, `dateTo` etc...

The react team has provided a nice eslint plugin ([eslint-plugin-react-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks)) that helps you fix these kind of issues, i recommend you to try it.

Comment: Thank You for help, nevertheless useEffect You quoted is used with empty array intentionally, so react fires it only once. I still can't solve this, maybe linter will help me. Do You have any helpful resources on how to use eslint react hooks plugin with create-react-app ? Thanks

Comment: You should always include dependencies, there are very few rare edge cases when you don't want a dependency. as for the eslint plugin support for create-react-app they included it in a recent version, you can read about it [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5602)